# Image shows in Expression Blend but not during runtime

Tags: silverlight, image, controltemplate, resourcedictionary

The image in question is located in a ControlTemplate inside of a ResourceDictionary similar to this (various details removed for clarity):

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageTestTemplate" TargetType="ImageTest">
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="/MyAssembly;Component/Images/MyImage.png"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

When I view the control in Expression Blend the image shows up just fine, but when I run the app the image does not show up. If I drop the same image into a UserControl it also shows up just fine, so the problem has something to do with using the template.

Is there some other way I should be loading the image resource inside the template?

Comment: What I ended up doing was making a new usercontrol that is basically a wrapper for an Image control. It has one property "Source" which is just a pass through for the wrapped Image control's "Source" property. Using this wrapper control from the template works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the leading '/'. The base resource path I'm using for a project is "IMLPrototype2;component/Model/Sounds/" in SL 3 & 4.

Comment: I've tried it without the leading '/'. It still doesn't show.